# How to get the crc32 of a resource in the response headers?

Tags: http, crc, crc32, request-headers, response-headers

I need to get a CRC32 checksum of a file i'm downloading through an http GET request - without actually opening the response body.

I am building a proxy app - which gets a request from a client, and does the actual GET call. I'd like the response the proxy gets from the server to contain the checksum, without having to read through the actual data in the response body. I connect the response body reader stream, to the writer stream which I return to the client.

I read about the "Want-Digest" header which I can add to the request, and should result in the response containing a "Digest" header, with a checksum - but it did not work.
I also looked into the Content-MD5 header, but when I try to download some photos, I see i'm not getting it in the response (also, I read that it is deprecated).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: simply set the CRC 32 in the response header.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I'm talking about the response that the proxy gets from the server he's redirecting the request to. I want to get the checksum without actually reading the entire file and calculating it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any headers, such as 'Want-Digest' or 'Content-MD5', will be up to the server to implement. Most servers will probably ignore those headers, which is why they aren't working for you. If you want to calculate the CRC32 of the body, you'll have to open the body and calculate it yourself.

If you have access to the TCP headers I suppose you could access the TCP checksum, though that is a relatively weak checksum even compared to CRC32, and it is also a checksum of the entire packet, not just the body.